# Why is visual studio code uninstalling a PDF on both my laptop and desktop?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Today when starting up vscode on both my laptop and desktop I got this notification popup in the lower right corner:

```
We have uninstalled 'tomoki1207.pdf' which was reported to be problematic.
```

At first on my desktop I just ignored it, but now on my laptop I am getting supsicious. I grepped my filesystem, I don't even have that tomoki1207.pdf anywhere on my filesystem (obviously not present if it was deleted but I checked my backup and it was not there)

Answer (score 1):

After toggling on the developer tools and filtering for "tomoki" I found out that it was actually not a file that got "uninstalled", but it was an extension. This is the logline:

```
INFO Uninstalling the extension tomoki1207.pdf-0.4.1 from window 1
```

It was deleted because of the Event Stream vulnerability that popped up a few days ago: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2018/11/26/event-stream
https://blog.npmjs.org/post/180565383195/details-about-the-event-stream-incident